# Get Adapter or Object value from Spinner selection

Tags: java, android, spinner, adapter

Here is my spinner setup:

```
 ArrayAdapter<SubCategory> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<SubCategory>(AddLocationActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, scList);

    // populate spinner
    s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.subCatSpinner);
    s.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
             // WHAT DO I PUT HERE TO GET ID? 
            }


        });
    }
```

Here is the Object that the adapter is populated with:

```
public class SubCategory {
    public String subcategory;
    public long subcat_id;

    public SubCategory(String subcategory, long subcat_id) {
        this.subcategory = subcategory;
        this.subcat_id = subcat_id;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return subcategory;
    }
}
```

It has two properties:  Subcategory and it's ID.

The subcategory populates the adapter just fine, but I want to grab its ID when that option on the spinne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`getItem()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem%28int%29) in the Adapter, as in:

```
SubCategory sc = dataAdapter.getItem(position);
```

You also need to mark your `dataAdapter` declaration as `final` for this to work.

Comment: Perfect.  That was it!  A basic one I was overthinking.